# How to set OUT parameter in Java Quarkus reactive client?

Tags: java, oracle, quarkus

I need to send a parameter of type OUT in the call to the stored procedure, I can't find a way to declare (instead of "OUTparameter") it using quarkus-reactive-oracle-client

I use:

```
@Inject
io.vertx.mutiny.oracleclient.OraclePool client;
```

Fragment:

```
Uni<RowSet<Row>> rowSet = client.preparedQuery("{CALL RSMFE02PCK.GET_ALL_XML(?,?)}").execute(Tuple.of(contract, "OUTparameter"));
return rowSet.onItem().transformToMulti(set -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(set)).onItem().transform(row -> row.getString(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported yet (as of Vert.x 4.3.4). I have [filed an issue](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/issues/1246), hopefully we can get it in the next release.

In the meantime, as a workaround, you may invoke the Oracle JDBC driver on a worker thread.